# Why did all of my objects disappear when sculpting?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, sculpt

I was sculpting then suddenly all of my objects disappeared! I'm not in local view, I added a new cube, I can see it fine, but I cannot seem to make any other object to show.

I think this might be a bug? The objects are still there in the bar, with the modifiers and all, I cant see or edit them. I cannot leave my meshes that I worked on for days there and try again.

They also aren't hidden. I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, nothing changes. Just so you know.

Comment: Did you hide the collection by accident? If so, it will look like a "smile" instead of an "eye" in the scene tree. Things hidden this way are still visible in the tree, but grayed out, and ALT+H wont bring them back, you have to click the collection.

Comment: oh weird... I was sure i added the picture too...
but no, theyre just eyes.